# Python: TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes

Tags: python, list, pygame, typeerror

I'm trying to blit a list on to a surface in pygame, but the line `prompts = contactFont.render(fields, True, (171,0,0))` causes the above error and I don't know why.

```
class AddPage(Page):

    ...

    def textInputs(self):
        fields = ["First Name:", "Last Name:", "Address:", "Mobile:", "Telephone:", "Email:"]
        contactFont = pygame.font.SysFont("trebuchet ms", 18)
        y = 20

        for i in fields:
            #Error here
            prompts = contactFont.render(fields, True, (171,0,0))
            self.intermediate2.blit(prompts, (5,y))
            pygame.draw.line(self.intermediate2, (0,0,0), (5, (y+20)), (320, (y+20)), 1)
            y += 30
```

I tried encoding the `fields` list into unicode using `[x.encode('utf-8') for x in fields]` but nothing happened, what gives?

Comment: you probably meant `for name in fields: render(name, ...)` instead of fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Font.render()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) takes a *string* as first argument, but you are passing in the whole `fields` list instead.

You wanted to pass in `i`, I think:

```
for i in fields:
    prompts = contactFont.render(i, True, (171,0,0))
```

I'd use a more descriptive name than `i` here though; perhaps `field` or `prompt` is a better choice.

Comment: Whoopsie! Thank you very much. I will accept your answer in 10 mins.